# implementing jump-statement in ast-walking interpreter

Tags: interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree, break, goto

In an ast-walking interpreter, the code is executed node by node. How can I implement features like goto, break or continue? I stop the current execution and jump to another node? Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is "don't interpret ASTs for languages with gotos".

Fundamentally any kind of discontinuity in the tree walk causes serious slowdown if the language is processing mostly scalars.  (If your language processes complex values mostly, like the array language APL, it won't matter).

The best you can hope for is to pre-walk the tree and determine where the gotos actually go in the AST, and record that in an associative cache off to the side.  Then when you encounter a goto, simply consult the cache rather than searching the tree.

But this is the first step down the road toward compiling, e.g., precomputing what you can before you execute.

Comment: Thank you. What is the best way to interpret languages? I already wrote my parser which builds an AST.

Comment: A much better approach IMHO is to walk your AST, generate so-called threaded code, and execute that.  Threaded code is a virtual instruction set consisting of opcodes which are actually pointers to the execution routine for the opcode.  The interpreter is implemented in assembly as "fetch next threaded code opcode via a simulated PC; increment the simulated PC; jump indirect through the pointer".  This bit of code is attached to the *end* of each opcode execution routine.  Such interpreters are easy to generate code for, and are very fast for interpreters in terms of execution.

Comment: Thank you :). Are there any tutorials or guidelines on generating threaded code? I think interpreting these instructions is not that difficult ([link](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/threaded-code.html#switch-threading)). But at first I have to define my own virtual instruction set?

Comment: I read about it now and built a little example in java ([link](http://www52.zippyshare.com/v/15213731/file.html)). Can you look about the code please? I just want to know if this is the way to go.